# extending functions in F#

Tags: f#

in the following code the executeProg function is executing the program instructions list. 
it's execute the program with "PUSH ax, POP bx ..etc".

```
//Execute a program as a list of operations. Note how pc is incremented
//so any jump instruction must be written carefully.
let mutable executeProg = fun (program:operation list) ->
  pc <- 0
  fault <- false
  while not(fault) && pc<program.Length do
    let instruction = program.[pc];
    execute instruction
    pc <- pc+1
  // end of while by indentation
  if not(fault) then printfn "top of stack holds value %d" (RAM.[sp-1]);
```

what I'm trying to do is: modify the executeProg so it would do the following:

```
push ax
pop bx      --> replace with single instruction mov ax bx 

push ax
pop ax      --> eliminate altogether

mov ax bx
mov bx ax   -->   mov ax bx
```

My question is, how would I implement a new executeProg modullary without change the original one?
my code is as the following:

```
let rec optimize = fun newProgram program ->
    let mutable newProgram = newProgram
    match program with
    | (PUSH(Reg(a)):: POP(Reg(b)) :: r) when String.Equals(a,b) ->
        optimize newProgram r
    | (PUSH(Reg(a)):: POP(Reg(b)) :: r) ->
        newProgram <- newProgram @ [MOV(Reg(a),Reg(b))]
        optimize newProgram r
    | (PUSH(Imm(a)):: POP(Imm(x)):: r) when a = x ->
        optimize newProgram r 
    | (MOV(Reg(a), Reg(b)) :: MOV(Reg(b), Reg(a)) :: r) ->
        newProgram <- newProgram @ [MOV(Reg(a),Reg(b))]
        optimize newProgram r
    | (a::r) ->
        newProgram <- newProgram @ [a]
        optimize newProgram r
    | [] -> newProgram
```

I'm new to F# language and I'm wondering if my syntax is correct. 
Would be grateful for any help
Thank you.

Comment: The compiler will tell you whether your syntax is correct or not. Do you get any error messages? If so, have you tried fixing them? If no, does the program work as expected or not?

Comment: Actually, I edited my code above and fix the compiler errors. it's working now foe the first two requirements. I'm wondering how would I do the patterns for the last two requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you don't need to have a mutable function. Perhaps you can change the design to use immutable, composable structures that will allow you to add new functionality to your solution.

I played with the problem a bit and here's what I got.

Declare types that you will use in the program:

```
type Register = 
    | AX 
    | BX

type Operand =
    | Register of Register
    | Int of int


type Command = 
| MOV of Register * Operand
| PUSH of Operand
| POP of Operand

type FnBinaryOp = Register -> Operand -> Command
type FnUnaryOp = Operand -> Command

type Program = Command list

//two helper functions to save some typing
let i n = Int n
let r n = Register n

//helper functions to clarify the declaration syntax
let mov:FnBinaryOp = 
    fun reg op -> MOV (reg, op)

let push: FnUnaryOp = fun op -> PUSH (op)

let pop: FnUnaryOp = fun op -> POP (op)
```

Implement your optimization method - it returns the modified instruction list. This is where the code inefficiencies are rectified.

```
///optimize the program - remove cancelling stack commands, simplify MOV commands
let optimize (program:Program) = 
   let rec recOptimize stack prog = 
       match prog with
       | PUSH (Register r1)::POP (Register r2)::xs when r1 = r2 -> //push ax; pop ax => nop
           xs |> recOptimize stack
       | PUSH (Register r1)::POP (Register r2)::xs when r1 <> r2 -> //push ax; pop bx => move ax bx
           xs |> recOptimize (MOV(r1, Register(r2))::stack)
       | PUSH (Int i1)::POP (Int i2)::xs when i1 = i2 -> //push 3; pop 3 => nop
           xs |> recOptimize stack
       | ((MOV (r1, Register r2 )) as op1)::((MOV (r3, Register r4 )) as op2)::xs when r1 = r4 && r2 = r3 -> //move ax bx; move bx ax => move ax bx
           xs |> recOptimize (op1::stack)
       | ((MOV (r1, Register r2 )) as op1)::((MOV (r3, Register r4 )) as op2)::xs when r1 = r3 && r2 = r4 -> //move ax bx; move ax bx => move ax bx
           xs |> recOptimize (op1::stack)
       | op::xs -> //all other cases - pass through
           xs |> recOptimize (op::stack)
       | [] -> stack

   program 
   |> recOptimize []
```

Implement the actual execution of your program (not implemented here)

```
let runProgram (program:Program) = 
    let rec run stack prog =
        []
    program |> run []
```

And this is how you can invoke this:

```
let program:Program = [
    mov AX (r BX)
    push (r BX)
    pop (r BX)
    mov AX (r BX)
    ]

program 
|> optimize 
|> runProgram
```

If you need to add new functionality to the optimization step, you can just replace the optimize element of the composite call.
You can run multiple passes of optimize to cover for cases where certain operations become 'paired' and you want to optimize them as well.
    program 
    |> optimize 
    |> optimize 
    |> runProgram

Here is a few tests:

```
[<Fact>]
let ``push 42; pop 42 => nop`` () =
    let program:Program = [
        push (i 42)
        pop (i 42)
        ]
    let optimized = program |> optimize

    //should be reduced to empty list
    Assert.Empty(optimized)

[<Fact>]
let ``push ax; pop ax => nop`` () =
    let program:Program = [
        push (r AX)
        pop (r AX)
        ]
    let optimized = program |> optimize

    //should be reduced to empty list
    Assert.Empty(optimized)

[<Fact>]
let ``push ax; pop bx => move ax bx`` () =
    let program:Program = [
        push (r AX)
        pop (r BX)
        ]
    let optimized = program |> optimize

    //should be reduced to a single element list mov ax bx
    let expected = MOV( AX, (r BX))
    let op = optimized.Head
    Assert.Equal(1, optimized.Length)
    Assert.Equal(expected, op)

[<Fact>]
let ``move ax bx; move bx ax => move ax bx`` () =
    let program:Program = [
        mov AX (r BX)
        mov BX (r AX)
        ]
    let optimized = program |> optimize

    //should be reduced to a single element list mov ax bx
    let expected = MOV( AX, (r BX))
    let op = optimized.Head
    Assert.Equal(1, optimized.Length)
    Assert.Equal(expected, op)

[<Fact>]
let ``run optimize on program`` () =
    let program:Program = [
        mov AX (r BX)
        push (r BX)
        pop (r BX)
        mov AX (r BX)
        ]
    let optimized = program 
                    |> optimize
                    |> optimize
                    |> optimize

    //should be reduced to a single element list mov ax bx
    let expected = MOV( AX, (r BX))
    let op = optimized.Head
    Assert.Equal(1, optimized.Length)
    Assert.Equal(expected, op)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what if I have a sequence like : push 3 pop 4 pop ax pop bx ? (I edited my code above).

Comment: Ok i don't see the change you made, but if this sequence: push 3 pop 4 pop ax pop bx is correct, aren't you running out of stack? One push and three pop operations are not possible on a stack. If you mean push 3; push 4; pop ax; pop bx; then you just need to add pattern similar to the third pattern in my example.

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes that what I meant. You may see the update I made to my function.Thank You.